# 500 internal server error from html5boilerplates .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, html5boilerplate

I just uploaded a html5boilerplate project to my apache server and I get a 500 internal server error. If I remove the .htaccess file it works.
I havn't touched the .htaccess file, what's wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at Boilerplate's official project page you should edit your .htaccess file according to some [guidelines](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/htaccess/). Then run `sudo apachectl restart` and you're done.